# How to create text file with clipboard data

Tags: tcl

I have copied data to clipboard from my application.
Now I want to store (paste) clipboard data in new notepad file.
I will be using this script in Windows & Linux env. 
Please help..

Answer (score 1):

You get the contents of the clipboard with `clipboard get`. You can then pick a file to save to using `tk_getSaveFile`, and do the save with `open` and `puts`.

```
package require Tk

wm withdraw .; # Hide the default window
update
set contents [clipboard get]

set filename [tk_getSaveFile -defaultextension .txt]

# Skip saving if we got the empty name; it signifies that the user cancelled
if {$filename ne ""} {
    set f [open $filename "w"]
    puts $f $contents
    close $f
}

exit
```

Comment: Yes Sir [clipboard get] perfectly works in windows environment if used package require Tk this needs to check on Linux. Thanks